# Film about a dad who lost his son in Halloween party

Tags: identify-this-movie

Hi friends just want to know the name of a movie that I have watched last year or so.

The story is about a father bringing a son to a Halloween party but the son got lost. The father looked for his son and was eventually lead to an old man who opened a wall for him to go through. Beyond the wall was a thin bridge, and the first thing he saw was three dead people hanged on poles. Then there was a house, and a lot of children were in the basement. He finally managed to look for his son and together took along two other unknown kids and barely made through the flimsy bridge and back home.

Maybe from 2014 or 2015. The guy is of medium built and just to add on, the son is seeing faces of a certain person days before the Halloween carnival and there is also a story of a women being burnt alive together with her two children long time back. Language is English and it is aired in Singapore also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Pay The Ghost](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3733778/combined) from 2015 with    Nicolas Cage.

> One year after Mike Lawford's young son disappeared during a Halloween carnival, he is haunted by eerie images and terrifying messages he can't explain. Together with his estranged wife, he will stop at nothing to unravel the mystery and find their son-and, in doing so, he unearths a legend that refuses to remain buried in the past.

It was based on a novella by Tim Lebbon. All the details you mentioned are there, and you can see some of them (like the old man and the flimsy bridge) in the trailer:

Comment: Okayh thanks Walt!!! I've been thinking bout tis for days.. have a great day! ^^